# Module packs with ocamlbuild

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I have the following file hierarchy:

```
foo.mlpack
Foo/
   bar.ml
   baz.ml
foo.ml
```

and I want to be able to do the following:

```
let () =
  Foo.Bar.some_func1 ();
  Foo.Baz.some_func2 ();
  Foo.some_func3 ()
```

How can I tell ocamlbuild to take `foo.ml` into account when creating the `Foo` module?

### Edit 1

Thanks to the answer of daniel-bünzli, I was able to do what I wanted. So now, I'm in the following scenario:

```
_tags

foo.mllib
foo.ml
Foo/
   bar.ml
   baz.ml

toto.mllib
toto.ml
Toto/
    ...
    bar.ml
    ...
```

The problem now is that `Toto.Bar` seems to be occluded by `Foo.Bar`. I can't access `Toto.Bar`'s content.

### Edit 2

Ok in fact it's not a real problem.

I've just renamed `Foo/bar.ml` -> `Foo/fooBar.ml`.

So I have the following in `foo.ml`:

```
module Bar = FooBar
```

If I understand correctly, the guys from Jane Street do the same thing in `Core_kernel` with `Core_list` and some other modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `mlpack`.

Simply define your foo.ml as follows:

```
module Bar = Bar
module Baz = Baz
let some_func3 () = ...
```

Then simply define a `.mllib` with

```
Foo
```

Don't forget to `<Foo> : include` in your `_tags` file.

Comment: Thanks I'm trying it right now. Let's say I also have `<root>/Toto/bar.ml`. Will it conflict with `<root>/Foo/bar.ml`?

Comment: This method doesn't seem to work in the case mentioned in my comment above.